# iOS - Interface Builder - subviews not inheriting superview alpha

Tags: ios, uiview, interface-builder, alpha, subviews

In Interface Builder, I have laid a UIView on the the main view of a ViewController.
On that UIView I have added a number of elements so that when I reduce the alpha of that view to 0,
all of the elements will have their alpha reduced. This is the normal behaviour expected but it is not working.

Has anyone experienced this before?

[image]

As the image shows, The subviews ("image View - Transaction..." etc) are not inheriting the alpha of 'View'

Comment: Show how you're laying out the views and adding them as subviews.

Comment: Updated question for this. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of setting alpha to 0 set background color of parent view to 'Clear Color' and set alpha back to 1.

Comment: This would not achieve what I want.

Answer (score 0):

First see your self.Because if you set alpha to your superview in that case your view will be disappear so in that case how can you see you subview. And try to use this one sure you will see your view with transparent.And second thing Do you know the mean of `alpha = 0`.

```
 for (UIView *subview in [self.view subviews])
    {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIView class]])
        {
            subview.alpha = 0.5;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I know that this is possible but I don't want to resort to this. I just need the view to behave normally. There must be something that I am doing wrong in IB.

Comment: Try to see in your self.Because if you set alpha to your superview in that case your view will be disappear so in that case how can you see you subview.

Comment: Have you got your solution ?

Comment: Not yet and again, The problem is that Interface builder is not recognizing the subviews as subviews. I need to know why and how to fix it in Interface Builder.

Comment: if you set alpha = 0 it means you'll get dissappear that view.So i'll suggest do alpha = .5f in that case you can see your all subviews.

Comment: Again, The problem is that Interface builder is not recognizing the subviews as subviews. I need to know why and how to fix it in Interface Builder. The alpha value is irrelevant to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I don't know the reason. But if you need to hide your views, you can use `hidden` property of your superview. In this case subviews inherit superview's property. It solved my problem.